# What is impact of increasing misfireThresold value?

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, quartz

I’m using quartz.net 3.5. We see a lot of misfires. Right now the value of misfireThresold value is 60 seconds. In production, the minimum recurring time for a job is 30 minutes.

so I’m thinking of increasing the value of 30 minutes or 20 minutes.

But before I make this change, I would like to know if is there any problem with increasing this value to such a high value.

By default, if a job is missed, it’s retried within the misfireThresold value based on the configured value of the misfire instruction. Also, I would like to know how does this work? Does it keep polling the database within this time period?

Just FYI sometimes there could be 2000 jobs scheduled per second.

I have posted on [GitHub](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/discussions/2247) as well, But posting here for better reach.